# threadsafe implementation of arraylist

Tags: java, concurrency

So if a program does this:

```
    static ArrayList<X> a = null;
    static{
            for(;;){X x = new X(); a.add(x)}
          }
```

and the only operations called after the static initializing, on the shared list, are get() and x.t()

```
       X x = a.get(i); x.t();
```

and X doesn't have access to container & is thread safe, that should mean that using Arraylist like this, without synchronization is thread safe, correct?

Comment: If the program starts with the `static` block code provides in your example, it will throw a `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: what does `t` do?  Or is `t` any arbitrary function we can think of?

Comment: change that null to a new Arraylist<>, qestion stands.

Comment: X is thread safe, so it doesn't matter what t does, its a public thread safe method inside X, operating entirely on x state.

Comment: I don't think that is true, what if X.t modifies the container?

Comment: ok, sure. i should say in the qustion that X doesn't have access to container.

Comment: Please modify the question to reflect that.

Comment: Not neccesarily. Two or more threads could do this: `public void someMethod(int x) { X x = a.get(x); a.remove(x);  }` in order to make this method thread safe, you should synchronize it yourself. The answer here is that the collection itself it's synchronized, but that doesn't save it for two or more threads to access and modify it's contents in a synchronized way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing is modifying the `ArrayList` than there is no reason that you should be worried about it's thread-safety.

That static block is thread-safe by default, because it's ran only once when the class is loaded (for initialization).

Comment: Agree. We just dont know what `t` does

Comment: ... but if you can't *guarantee* that nothing is modifying the `ArrayList`, then I would argue that you *should* be worried about its thread safety.

Comment: @DanielPryden: I agree with that. But it's not mentioned anywhere in the OP. My answer was based on "and the only operations called after the static initializing, on the shared list, are get() ...".

Answer (score 6):

If the intention is for the list to not be modified once it is created, then enforce that: wrap the `ArrayList` in a [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).

Better yet, if you have Guava available, use an [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html).

Answer (score 1):

Vector is the synchronized collection you want.

Just because the elements of the Collection are thread safe does not guarantee that the container itself is thread safe.  Based on my understanding of concurrency.

If `t` modifies the backing Collection it is not thread safe.  For instance `t` is defined as follows:

```
this.list.remove(this.x);
```

It would not be safe.

Comment: No, `Vector` is not the answer. Please read [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-collection/difference-between-vector-and-arraylist-in-java/).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if that was the reason for a down vote that is suspect at best.  A Vector is a perfectly legitimate collection to use in terms of a synchronization problem.

Comment: Down vote was mine. You should always prefer `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>()))` over `Vector` in modern Java because it makes the intent clearer. Better yet, use a lock-free implementation like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: In case you don't believe that `Vector` is not an option: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oracle : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html   does not have it deprecated so your argument is invalid on this one.

Comment: It's not in the JavaSE Docs but Java people says that `Vector` class is deprecated and you should not use it. You can google this and find lot of info about this (and I mean almost every people will say the same).

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safety is only an issue on writable objects. 
Once initialised, your ArrayList is immutable - thus thread safe. Consider using unmodifiable wrappers around your arraylist - it will

1. make clear the array is not meant to be modified
2. prevent accidental modifications in the future

Just for sake of completeness, please be aware of the fact that, while operations on the ArrayList are threadsafe, operation on the elements are not.